# add class name to element in uibinder xml file

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

The following replaces any current css class names. It appears to call `setStyleName`.

```
<g:DecoratorPanel styleName="{style.myCssClass}">
```

What I really want to do is add a class name, like calling `addStyleName`.

Is it possible to do what I'm attempting?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `addStyleNames` in such situations, like this:

```
<g:DecoratorPanel addStyleNames="{style.myCssClass}">
```

It's a little trick I picked up on the [GWT's Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/f64ff1677bc38338/43dc4c3e6ac5eea0) - too bad it's not (?) mentioned in the official documentation.

PS: I'm actually missing a really comprehensive documentation for UiBinder. I `grep`ped the GWT sources for `addStyleNames` and found this file: [WidgetBasedUi.ui.xml](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/test/com/google/gwt/uibinder/test/client/WidgetBasedUi.ui.xml) - it seems to contain some interesting use cases for UiBinder, including the one with `addStyleNames`.
If someone knows any other good/secret references for UiBinder, please share :)

Comment: I was close. I tried that, but missed the pluralization of the function name(addStyleName instead of addStyleNames).

Comment: The documentation at http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Stylish_World is fairly complete, and mentions the attribute. It is however more of a guide than a reference manual.

Answer (score 3):

Yes `addStyleNames` is the solution. And it is actually mentioned in the documentation: [UiObject](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html). See section "Use in UiBinder Templates".