# Eclipse autocompletion for GWT UiBinder (+ UiBinder documentation)

Tags: eclipse, gwt, autocomplete, uibinder

I am using UiBinder xml files in a GWT project. The problem is that Eclipse doesn't give me any info about what attribute I can use with the widgets

For example I know I can set width or style this way :

```
<g:HorizontalPanel width="100%" addStyleNames="{style.mainPanel}">
```

But they are not mentioned in the list that appears after clicking ctrl + space. So I don't know what other options I have. How can I get them ?

More generally I find it hard to find complete documentation on what we can do in the UiBinder. Which leads to spending a lot of time to find how to deal with [simple features like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038540/listbox-gwt-using-uibinder/) Has anybody got any good links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any attribute you pass, is converted to a method call on the object according to some naming guidelines:

- width="100%" --> this will call setWidth("100%")
- addStyleNames=".."
  -->    setAddStyleNames(...) does not exist,    so GWT will search for an
  operation    with that name:
  addStyleNames

If you follow these guidelines, you can check the Javadocs to see which operations can be executed.

If you are using GWT 2.1.0, you can have a look at the GWT Designer plugin for Eclipse. I have not used it yet, but I expect it to do the necessary.-

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked around for some third party tutorials/insights, since I found the ones provided by Google sufficient:

- [The official documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html)
- The javadocs for [`UiObject`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html) contain some additional info
- [Some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899007/add-class-name-to-element-in-uibinder-xml-file/1914393#1914393) I found [WidgetBasedUi.ui.xml](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/test/com/google/gwt/uibinder/test/client/WidgetBasedUi.ui.xml) in GWT's test suite, which contains some interesting use cases for UiBinder